# How do I query a subset of a Firebase Firestore collection in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firestore so I have a simple question:

Suppose I have a collection of **users** and a collection of **groups**. **users** have an array field of **groupReferences** to mark what **groups** it is a part of.

Now I want to query a subset of the collection of **groups** that matches those that a particular **user** is within.

Do I:

- Pull all **groups** and somehow compare the references in the **user**, filtering out any that match?
- Iterate through the **user**'s references and pull each **group** one at a time?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would go for the second option. But - depends on the number of groups and users really.